# The passes() function of custom validation rule is ignored

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.8

I don't know if its my lack of sleep or missing something obvious, but I'm having this problem: I've created a custom validation rule and I need to pass a request value through the constructor to perform a validation.

This is my setup:

#### Custom validation rule

```
/** Rules/RouteValidationRule.php */

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class RouteValidationRule implements Rule {

    private $action;

    public function __construct(string $action)
    {
        $this->action = $action; // doing dd($action) output the correct value.
    }

    // a dd('Hi'); inside here is just ignored:
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        if ($this->action === 'complete')
            return (isset($value['delivery_route']))
                && (count($value['delivery_route']) >= 2);
        else
            return true;
    }

    public function message() { /** */ }
}
```

#### Form Request

```
/** UpdateOrderRequest.php */

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Rules\OrderStatusesRule;
use App\Rules\RouteValidationRule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UpdateOrderRequest extends FormRequest {

    public function authorize() { /** */ }

    public function rules() 
    {
        return [
            'action' => ['required', new OrderStatusesRule],
            'meta.delivery_route' => [
                'array',
                new RouteValidationRule($this->get('action')), // <---
           ],
        ];
    }
}
```

But the thing is, the value is reaching the custom rule constructor, but it doens't get to the `passes()` method, it simply ignore this and goes on as if this were ok.

PD: I've check every step with `dd()`.

Thanks in advance.

---

### Update

```
/** MyController.php */

    /**
     * @param UpdateOrderRequest $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(UpdateOrderRequest $request) // the RequestForm is injected
    {
        dd('I passed');  // <-- is reaching this statement when it shouldn't
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste the controller handler method as well? Also couldn't it be that your request validation fails at a previous step and therefore it won't reach your validation rule because of a fast exit strategy?

Comment: @Tacsiazuma That's the thing, it is passing the validation and reaching the controller. I'll add the related code as suggested.

Comment: And if you check the request in your controller, it contains the mentioned field? What happens if you add 'required' as a rule?

Comment: @Tacsiazuma if I add `required` as a rule in that attribute it fails when missing (as expected) but then when I add the parameter and redo the request, it passes the `required` but ignores the `passes()` custom rule. And yeah, the attribute reaches the controller, This is really weird

Answer (score 4):

The reason your rule wouldn't run is because the attribute you are testing isn't in the `Request` or null. If you want the rule to run whether it's present or not, have your rule implement `ImplicitRule` not `Rule` e.g.:

```
class RouteValidationRule implements ImplicitRule {
```

Answer (score 0):

I hacked together a similar solution and found out that it just ignores the validation if the field to be validated is not present (except when required is also added as a validation rule):

```
Route::any('/', function (UpdateOrderRequest $orderRequest) {
    dd($orderRequest);
});
```

I added a dd('pass') inside the passes method:

```
 public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        dd('pass');
        if ($this->action === 'complete')
            return (isset($value['delivery_route']))
                && (count($value['delivery_route']) >= 2);
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Then sent a request with postman:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 848f7181-2c28-46a5-b508-4cb35083315e
{
    "action" : "something",
    "meta" : {
        "delivery_route" : "something else"
    }
}------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

It ran into the passes method and echoed 'pass' back. Then I renamed the "delivery_route" above and it ended up in the controller.

From the Laravel validation docs:

> By default, when an attribute being validated is not present or
>   contains an empty string, normal validation rules, including custom
>   extensions, are not run.

Comment: I don't get this solution, or it is a confirmation that is not a problem on my end? (a possible bug maybe)

Comment: I did put the attribute present with a value that should have break the validation but still passed.

Comment: Because the field name does not match I guess. Read about Implicit extensions in https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation

Comment: I made a request with the same attribute names, Really weird stuff, to be honest.

Comment: Can you try it with a JSON request  (if it's not that already) and update your question with the request body?